# confirm if ${2n \choose n}=2^{2n}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

please verify if the following is true. I have tried but I could not get $2^n$

$$\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k}^2= {2n \choose n}=2^{2n}$$

Comment: Well, as this is not true it will be hard to verify. Take $n=1$, then $\binom21=2\ne4=2^2$.

Comment: ${2n\choose n}$ **isn't** $2^{2n}$.

Comment: It's also not $2^n$. Try for $n=2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple contre-example :

Take $ n=2 $, $ \binom{2n}{n}=\binom{4}{2}=6 $, and $ 2^{2n}=2^{4}=16 \cdot $

Thus "$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ \binom{2n}{n}= 2^{2n} $" is a false predicate.